# Physical problem with Fourier transformation by diffraction at a slit?

Tags: optics, visible-light, differentiation, fourier-transform, wavelength

It is well known (and observed experimentally every time) that after passing through a slit the light doesn't change its wavelength. From the other side it is also well known that when the light passes through a slit one has (in order to explain why the light spreads thereafter) to apply Fourier transformation and then there occur a range of frequencies which of course means a superposition of waves with many different wavelengths (WL). What have these waves (and their WL) to do with the incident wave and its WL? Where do they disappear after the slit because there is again only the WL of the incident wave to be observed after the slit? In the end is Fourier just a mathematical trick or do these waves have a physical existence?

Answer (score 2):

The optical wavelength does not change.  The Fourier transform goes from the spatial domain to the spatial-frequency domain.  There is a range of spatial frequencies (all same optical wavelength) in the beam prior to the slit, so after the slit there is a diffraction pattern that represents all of the spatial frequencies in the light.

Comment: I don't see any explanation in this answer. You just repeat the statements in the question. The sentences "There is a range of spatial frequencies (all same optical wavelength) etc." are completely incomprehensible. What do you mean by that. Please extend.

Comment: Jason's answer is not just restating your question for your question carries a non-sensical part "there occur a range of frequencies which of course means a superposition of waves with many different wavelengths". The only frequencies relevant to diffraction are *spatial* frequencies, they are neither *temporal* frequencies nor waves with "many  wavelengths". You may say these are various projections of the wavevector into various directions, but their reciprocals are not *really* wavelengths of a wave as that is commonly understood.

Comment: Here is an external link about spatial frequency in optics:
https://spie.org/publications/tt52_12_spatial_frequency?SSO=1

Comment: I second @hyportnex. I think OP needs to have a better understanding that $\vec{k}$ vectors and their spatial distribution is "disentagled" from their temporal distribution and temporal frequencies. I guess to better understand this the concept that the spread is just a change in the direction of the momemta of the light, while the quanta of energy (wavelength or time frequency) remains the same. The $\vec{k}$ directions get filtered by a spatial component, but their amplitude remains the same, only the new distribution is pointing towards different directions.

Comment: Spatial frequency is about decomposing the spatial shape of the beam into sine/cosine waves.  For example, a monochromatic beam passing through a square slit has a spatial-frequency spectrum that is the two-dimensional Fourier transform of the square slit, which is a two-dimensional sinc function.  This the shape of the intensity pattern seen on a screen that is placed beyond the slit.

Comment: @JoséAndrade But are not the Energy (temporal frequency) and k vector in fact connected as p=hk and E=pc? Or is this k  something else?

Comment: @hyportnex But when one is about to introduce a partially localized object in QM he/she uses a packet of temporal? waves, I have that impression at least. No one talks about spatial wave packet??

Comment: forget QM, that has nothing to with this. Take an LC filter and pass a square pulse (a temporal "wave packet") through it and you get ripples when it comes out but that does not change "frequencies" of anything. Those ripples are "diffraction in time" ripples. You partially obstruct a propagating wave by a screen and a slot, a spatial filter, you get ripples in space, ie.,  "spatial  diffraction". It is all just Fourier sum/decomposition.

Comment: @hyportnex I think I understand what you and other mean. The wave is exp(iwt)exp(-ipx) and at a fixed time one has a region Dx = (-a,a) of values of the wave not zero. That is a function of x and it can be represented as integral over frequencies (spatial) and when Dx is smaller there are more frequencies so the integral to be not zero only on this Dx. So w and E=hw stay constant and the spatial frequencies diminish as Dx grows after a slit.

Comment: @hyportnex But my concerns are about a slit and its QM interpretation. So everything is OK but I just wonder that in QM a wave packet which is localized is constructed by a superposition of different E's not just one E and spatial frequencies.

Comment: So these two concepts seem to contradict each other. I think the spatial frequencies p=hk are connected with temporal frequencies (E=pc) and if one has spatial frequencies because of nonemptyness of the Dx region one necessarily also has temporal frequencies.

Comment: @hyportnex By the way "forget about QM" does not answer the questions where do all spatial modes vanish when there is only one particle. QM answer is collapse of wavefunction.

Comment: Sincerely, the QM interpretation holds also in electromagnetic packets. $\vec{k}$ is a vector. It has amplitude (which is connected to $\omega$) and a direction which has nothing to do with time. A packet passing through a slit  (if small enough) "de"-selects directions and localizes a point-source (if you just see it from above), which both affect the direction of the $\vec{k}$-vectors, but not their amplitude. A single frequency laser will still be single frequency after a slit, you just force the decomposition of the directions of all the present $\vec{k}$-vectors.

Comment: But the point of hyportnex is to disentangle your mind of QM interpretations, which are not needed to understand EM-theory and what happens to light.

Comment: @JoséAndrade I think by Fourier theorem exactly the amplitude of k is what changes and from few k vectors in the superposition (wide area of the beam) one receives many different values for more vectors k of different amplitudes (different wavelengths) (narrow slit). And as you say it is connected to w.

Comment: Ok, your problem is also in mixing total mometum of a light beam, expressed by $\vec{k}$ which means a sum of all individual photons, and the k vector of individual photons. A gaussian beam has an infinite distribution of directions for its individual photon k vectors, but their amplitude is always the same, because that is entangled to their frequency. Once you use a slit, you change the spatial distribution, but again, the individual photon k vectors remain with the same amplitude.